# Convert regexp query to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to convert this query to SQL Server. It basically removes all non numbers except + in the phone number so I can match it with +19123123123.

```
select phone
from users
where regexp_replace(phone, '[^+0-9]', '') = '+19123123123'
```

For example:

```
19123123123
+1 912 123 123
1 912 123 123
(+1) 912 123 123
(+1)912-123-123
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is rather tricky in SQL Server.  But one way that comes close is:

```
select v.*, replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(phone, ',', ''), ')', ''), '(', ''), ' ', ''), '-', '')
from (values ('19123123123'),
             ('+1 912 123 123'),
             ('1 912 123 123'),
             ('(+1) 912 123 123'),
             ('(+1)912-123-123')
     ) v(phone)
where try_convert(decimal(20, 0), replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(phone, ',', ''), ')', ''), '(', ''), ' ', ''), '-', '')) = +19123123123
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5d090319bbc82104b51b673b7aa6c33d) is a db<>fiddle.

This isn't perfect, but it comes pretty close in SQL Server.

Comment: thanks, i tried your query but it returns no result for me. where phone = '+19123123123' has a result. is there anything i am missing? i tried your solution with a varchar but getting 'Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric.'